# Make taskbar icons' size bigger/smaller than options given Win 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar, icons

I am using Windows 8.1 and I want to make my taskbar icons size bigger/smaller than options given in settings.

If I set the option to bigger icons, it is to big:

[image: Bigger icons taskbar]

If I set it to small, it is incredibly small:

[image: Too small icons taskbar]

So, is there any way to adjust taskbar icon size without third party apps, maybe editing the registry?

Answer (score 9):

You could try to change DPI Scaling Size

go to Control Panel -> Personalization -> Display

- Method 1: uncheck the **Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays** and use the slider (smaller or gigger)
- Method 2: check the **Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays** and select one option from the radio boxes (and you can also check the **Custom sizing options**)

Comment: Method #1 worked for me! (Windows 10) I had tried fiddling with the resolution, but that didn't seem to resolve the problem. After adjusting the scale it worked perfectly. I got to that menu by typing "Scaling" into the Cortana search bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Right-click on the taskbar and press "Properties"
2. Select the checkbox for "Use small taskbar buttons"
3. Press OK

Comment: Doesn't address the question.

Comment: What do you think he did to make his taskbar small?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Windows 10. Windows 10 taskbar icon size is perfect.

I’ve tried a couple of customizing apps that seemed like they’d be able to do custom taskbar icon size (WinAero Tweaker, Actual Multiple Monitors), but they have no such option. So Windows 10 is all that I can say improves this from experience.

However, Windows 10 has some bugs that are not in 8.1. For example, I get DPC latency every 30 minutes, which causes one second of audio and video stutter. (Even though I updated BIOS and drivers frequently. This seems to be a quite common problem, although it doesn’t affect everybody with Win 10.)
So if you are willing to take some risk, Windows 10 definitely has a look that’s more optimized for desktop PCs than Windows 8.1.